# Centering my items in the middle of the screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, centering

Playing around with CSS and **centering items** can be a bit of a daunting task. I was looking around with https://www.w3schools.com/ and https://css-tricks.com/ website about **centering items**. I still find it confusing if you could help me achieve my goal as though I am making a website for myself while learning to code. I know a lot of HTML and CSS, but sometimes as you try to achieve what you envision, it can become quite difficult.

Here is my problem. I have been wanting my profile picture to be on the left column and while a summary text about me on the right column. A lot of people have been telling me to avoid floats so I can understand why and choose to either use flex, grids, or columns.

Recently, I just tried using columns, and so far I like it. Only problem though is that it messed up my nav bar which actually stretched across my desktop and then responsive once in tablet/mobile.

One more thing, as shown in the picture below, I would like my text box be a little bit more center so that it looks good when it is in desktop. Then once you shrink it down to tablet/mobile, I would like my profile picture to stack on top of my text box so that it also looks good when you're scrolling.

*NOTE:* I put a background color around my two objects so that I can see visually where it is and what the div box is doing. Then later I plan to remove it once I get it finalized.

[image]

**HTML**

```html
<span>
  <div class="summary">
    <div class="profilePicture" style="background-color: lightgreen;">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TKo40kR.jpg" style="width: 170px; height: 170px; border-radius:50%;">
    </div>
    <div class="profileSummary" style="font-size: 18px; background-color: lightblue;">
      Attentive alas because yikes due shameful ouch much kookaburra cantankerously up unbridled far vulnerably climbed aristocratically hired brusque fox said the therefore terrier scallop innocent on goodness mongoose woolly showed insistently and.
    </div>
  </div>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

body>span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.summary {
                                    /* Creates two columns */
  -webkit-column-count: 2;          /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;             /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
  margin: auto;                     /* Begin Centering */
  width: 60%;
  padding: 300px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.profilePicture {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: The mess comes from `body { display:table; }`. Whoever told you to do that was not really your friend. There are much better ways to center. Such as `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center`.

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu Haha that fixed the problem! The one who is not really my friend was CSS-Tricks.com's advice on centering. And now I have another problem. Looks good so far, but when in iPhone, it looks ugly. Take a look here https://i.imgur.com/r2T6Ihb.jpg

Comment: Obviously. Don't use columns. Use flexbox and switch from row to column on narrow devices. I'll add an example.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Looking forward to an example. And please be sure to also center the two items in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise against using `columns` unless you want your elements to well... be displayed like columns in a newspaper. Not only you can't center anything in `columns`, but when changing width, the children jump from one column to another which makes it difficult for users to keep track of what's going on (if the reading order matters for your layout).

In order to center anything on the entire screen, here's what you could use:

```css
.summary {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.profilePicture {
  padding: 2rem;
}
.profileSummary {
  max-width: 400px;
}
@media(max-width: 667px) { /* change breakpoint to what you want */
  .summary {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="summary">
    <div class="profilePicture" style="background-color: lightgreen;">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TKo40kR.jpg" style="width: 170px; height: 170px; border-radius:50%;">
    </div>
    <div class="profileSummary" style="font-size: 18px; background-color: lightblue;">
      Attentive alas because yikes due shameful ouch much kookaburra cantankerously up unbridled far vulnerably climbed aristocratically hired brusque fox said the therefore terrier scallop innocent on goodness mongoose woolly showed insistently and.
    </div>
  </div>
```

If you want the two elements to be spaced out evenly, instead of `justify-content: center` use `justify-content: space-evenly`. Example, with a wrapper that constraints the width on wider screens:

```css
.summary {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 992px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.profilePicture, 
.profileSummary {
  padding: 2rem;
}
.profileSummary {
  max-width: 400px;
}
@media(max-width: 667px) { /* change breakpoint to what you want */
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
body {margin: 0;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<div class="summary">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="profilePicture" style="background-color: lightgreen;">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TKo40kR.jpg" style="width: 170px; height: 170px; border-radius:50%;">
    </div>
    <div class="profileSummary" style="font-size: 18px; background-color: lightblue;">
      Attentive alas because yikes due shameful ouch much kookaburra cantankerously up unbridled far vulnerably climbed aristocratically hired brusque fox said the therefore terrier scallop innocent on goodness mongoose woolly showed insistently and.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Haha thanks! You the man! You would not believe how many times it took me to finally get such a simple reply while everyone else makes it much more complicated then I already wanted it to be. I want short, simple, and done in an instant! One last question if you don't mind. So when I tried space-evenly, it seems to be pretty far apart, what if I want it a bit closer by about 50% ish? Thanks.

Comment: Like somewhere between when you apply it at center and space-evenly if you know what I mean so that I can be more pleased with where I want it place in my page.

Comment: In order to achieve that, you need one more element between `.summary` and your elements. You want the wrapper to be centered in `.summary` and have a `max-width` of whatever makes sense to you (`1000px`?). You center the wrapper in summary and the two elements in wrapper.

Comment: Also FYI, I removed my background color and now it looks even better. I placed it there so I can see what my div box is doing "behind the scene"

Comment: I added an example using a wrapper to the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for such a fast respond! You just made my day! Now I can move on to other contents for my other pages in peace! This part was the trickiest part of my website. My goal was to make a clean looking home page.

Comment: You have a long road ahead. Take it one step at a time and you'll get wherever you want, faster than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="summary">
    <div class="profilePicture" style="background-color: lightgreen;">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TKo40kR.jpg" style="width: 170px; height: 170px; border-radius:50%;">
    </div>
    <div class="profileSummary" style="font-size: 18px; background-color: lightblue;">
      Attentive alas because yikes due shameful ouch much kookaburra cantankerously up unbridled far vulnerably climbed aristocratically hired brusque fox said the therefore terrier scallop innocent on goodness mongoose woolly showed insistently and.
    </div>
  </div>


.summary
{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-flow:column;

}
```